# ORM - rejection error: column "id" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, node-postgres, objection.js

I use **PostgreSQL** and [objection.js](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/) in Node.js back-end for ORM. I have only two simple tables with one-to-one relationship. I am not able to insert new record into a table.

I have a simple database schema with employee and salary table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_name VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO employee (employee_name) VALUES ('james');

CREATE TABLE salary (
  salary_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  employee_id SERIAL UNIQUE,
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee (employee_id),
  amount integer
);
```

If I want to create new salary record by objection.js:

```
Salary.query()
          .insert({ employee_id: 1, amount: 10 })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
```

I get error:

```
Unhandled rejection error: column "id" does not exist
at Connection.parseE (./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:546:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:371:19)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:22)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:197:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:589:20)
```

**testSalary.js**

```
const { Model, snakeCaseMappers } = require('objection');

class Salary extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'salary';
  }

  static get columnNameMappers() {
    return snakeCaseMappers();
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',

      properties: {
        salary_id: { type: 'integer' },
        employee_id: { type: 'integer' },
        amount: { type: 'integer' },
      },
    };
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      employee: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/testEmployee`,
        join: {
          from: 'salary.employee_id',
          to: 'employee.employee_id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

module.exports = Salary;
```

**testEmployee.js**

```
const { Model, snakeCaseMappers } = require('objection');

class Employee extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'employee';
  }

  static get columnNameMappers() {
    return snakeCaseMappers();
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',

      properties: {
        employee_id: { type: 'integer' },
        employee_name: { type: 'string' },
      },
    };
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      salary: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: `${__dirname}/testSalary`,
        join: {
          from: 'employee.employee_id',
          to: 'salary.employee_id',
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

module.exports = Employee;
```

Comment: According to the objection docs, you should create the tables with knex migrations.

Comment: @SamH. can you provide a link please? If I check [docs](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#getting-started), there is said: _The next step is to create some migrations and models and start using objection.js. The best way to get started is to check out the example project. The express example project is a simple express server. The example-requests.sh file contains a bunch of curl commands for you to start playing with the REST API._

Comment: http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#installation in the code sample in the getting started section. It's in a comment

Comment: @SamH. Thank you. If you write it as an answer, I can close my question and award your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if the supplied answer covers it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this has something to do with the reliance on Knex under the hood. In [the docs](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#installation), there is a code snippet that suggests that tables be created via Knex migrations. Maybe doing that will fix your problem, as Knex probably creates an id column that Objection expects to exist.

Answer (score 10):

Objection needs to be told what the id column is by defining `idColumn` on your `Model` classes.

```
class Salary extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return 'salary';
  }

  static get idColumn() {
    return 'salary_id';
  }
  // etc
}
```

Using migrations to create the tables will have made this work by creating the tables with their id column being named `id`, but you can use objection without migrations if you define the `idColumn`.